# Loop up and down

Tags: kotlin

I have the below code

```
(0..6).forEach { colorized(colors, it) }
(6 downTo 0).forEach { colorized(colors, it) }
```

Where I loop up and down. Is there a way to achieve it in one loop instead of two?

Comment: You can use a fancy mapping stage that turns 0..13 into 0..6..0. You can also use an old-school `while` loop.

Comment: Or you can just leave it like that, because it's probably more readable than what you would end up with.

Comment: Or you can use the following, but is it really more readable? `listOf((0..6), (6 downTo 0)).flatMap { it }.forEach { colorized(colors, it) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple extension on `IntRange` can solve it:

```
fun IntRange.forEachUpAndDown(action: (Int) -> Unit) {
    forEach(action)
    reversed().forEach(action)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    (0..6).forEachUpAndDown {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: `endInclusive downTo start` can be replaced with `reversed()` call.

Comment: I like this approach best, as I need to write `(0..6)` once, and also, I like the use of `reverse()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
(0..13).forEach { colorized(colors, if (it > 6)  13 - it else it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the two ranges as one:

`((0..6) + (6 downTo 0)).forEach { colorized(colors, it) }`

or try to reduce the count of parameters:

`with (6) { (0..this) + (this downTo 0) }.forEach { colorized(colors, it) }`

Comment: You missed a pair of parentheses in your 1st solution: ((0..6) + (6 downTo 0)).forEach { colorized(colors, it) }

Comment: @mTak Updated my answer. Thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy but ugly for performance way of doing it in only one loop:

```
inline fun<T> Iterable<T>.forEachUpDown(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (index in 0 until this.count()) {
        action(this.elementAt(index))
        action(this.elementAt(this.count()-index-1))
    }
}
```

and call:

```
(0..6).forEachUpDown {
        colorized(colors,it)
    }
```

as (0..6) is Iterable, it can only be traversed, and elements cannot be accessed by index.

A better for performance way of doing it in only one loop is this:

```
 val max=6
    for (index in 0 until max) {
        colorized(colors, index)
        colorized(colors, max-index-1)
    }
```

but, personally, I thin your way is clearer.